# number format in order by

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use a number format variable in php to sort in an order by case when function in mysql. I'm very new to mysql coding and the variable works in another set of php code that I have. Could someone please help me figure out why the variable will not sort correctly.

```
 <?php $price = number_format ($info['Price']/9,2);
 $order = mysqli_query($con, "
 SELECT DivisionOf, Manufacturer, Collection, Style, Price, ShowPrice, Include, Fiber, Width, Backing
...
GROUP BY ProductID

ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN ((Price <= '0.00') OR (Price >= '50.00') OR (ShowPrice!='Yes')) 
THEN Style ELSE 0 END asc,

CASE WHEN (Price > '0.00') AND (Price < '50.00') AND (ShowPrice='Yes') 
THEN $price ELSE 0 END asc,

CASE WHEN (Price > '0.00') AND (Price < '50.00') AND (ShowPrice='Yes') 
THEN Style ELSE Manufacturer END asc,

CASE WHEN (Price > '0.00') AND (Price < '50.00') AND (ShowPrice='Yes') 
THEN Manufacturer END asc;
");

 // Gather data from database
 mysqli_data_seek($order, 0);
 while($info = mysqli_fetch_array( $order ))

 include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$info['Include']);?>
```

Comment: `"why the variable will not sort correctly"` how do you expect it to sort? how is it sorting instead?

Comment: I've edited my post to show more of the code. I want it to order by the result of the $price variable. It skips that and orders by the Style instead. Does this help?

Comment: Since you're comparing strings, it will be a lexicographic order, not numeric order. E.g. `'12.00' < '2.00'`.

Comment: You should compare the numeric values instead of the formatted strings.

Comment: It does not sort by the numbers at all. It's like that case fails and it sorts by the next case.

Comment: Does it work correctly if you get rid of the quotes around the numbers?

Comment: The whole code breaks if I remove the quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a variable, I just changed the variable in the code to the format and it worked. i.e.

```
CASE WHEN (Price > '0.00') AND (Price < '50.00') AND (ShowPrice='Yes') 
THEN $price ELSE 0 END asc,
```

to

```
CASE WHEN (Price > '0.00') AND (Price < '50.00') AND (ShowPrice='Yes') 
THEN FORMAT (Price/9,2) ELSE 0 END asc,
```